# Matlab: produce a text file containing text and numbers from a loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I would like to produce a text file containing the following (with exact line breaks):

```
EXIT
POWDER DIFFRACTION (2-D)
C:\Users\themosawi\folder\file_0100.tif
EXIT
POWDER DIFFRACTION (2-D)
C:\Users\themosawi\folder\file_0101.tif
EXIT
POWDER DIFFRACTION (2-D)
C:\Users\themosawi\folder\file_0102.tif
EXIT
```

I wrote the following code

```
for i = 100:102
j = sprintf('%04d', i)
k = (['EXIT','',...
'POWDER DIFFRACTION (2-D)','',...
'C:\Users\themosawi\folder\file_' j '.tif']);
end
fid=fopen('MyFile.txt','w');
fprintf(fid, k);
fclose(fid);
```

But I am getting a text file with a single line containing this:

```
EXITPOWDER DIFFRACTION (2-D)C:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your loop, you only store the last value for `k`. You then open the file *outside* of your loop and write only the last `k`. You should consider opening the file *before* the loop and then write to it within the loop (using `fprintf`).

```
% Open the file
fid = fopen('MyFile.txt', 'w');

for k = 100:102
    % Write an entry in the file for this value of k
    fprintf(fid, 'EXIT\r\nPOWDER DIFFRACTION (2-D)\r\nC:\\Users\\themosawi\\folder\\file_%04d.tif\r\n', k);
end

% Close the file
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Thanks. The text file I am getting still contains one line and is missing information: `EXIT
POWDER DIFFRACTION (2-D)
C:EXIT
POWDER DIFFRACTION (2-D)
C:EXIT
POWDER DIFFRACTION (2-D)
C:`. I am also getting the follwing warning: ` Warning: Escaped character '\U' is not valid. See doc sprintf for
supported special characters.`

Comment: I just added your edited version, now I have all information but with no line breaks. any ideas?

Comment: @Mosawi What are you using to view the resulting file?